# boost fusion copy smaller sequence into larger sequence

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

Up until now, i was copying a src fusion sequence into a dst fusion sequence.

```
struct Dst { ... } dst;
boost::fusion::copy( src, dst );
```

However, dst, which is a struct adapted as a fusion sequence has a new member, placed last.

src's size has not changed though.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just keep the same code.

The first fields will be copied as ever, and the trailing, new, field is left untouched:

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec70362f0017a15)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/auxiliary/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fus = boost::fusion;

struct X {
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string s;
    std::string extra;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(X, (int,i)(double,d)(std::string,s)(std::string,extra))

int main()
{
    fus::vector<int, double, std::string> src(42, 3.14, "hello");

    X dst { -1, -1, "filler", "filler" };

    fus::copy(src, dst);

    std::cout << fus::as_vector(dst);
}
```

Prints

```
(42 3.14 hello filler)
```

Comment: there is this code in copy.hpp:          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( result_of::size<Seq1>::value == result_of::size<Seq2>::value);                          How is it that it is compiling for you?

Comment: It was changed between [v1.54](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/fusion/algorithm/auxiliary/copy.hpp) and [v.1.55](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/fusion/algorithm/auxiliary/copy.hpp)

Comment: @MMM I'm sure you can buy a newer version :)

Comment: is there a way to use a view to copy the minimum of the 2 sequences?

Comment: Yes. To do it generically, that'll be a bit of TMP, but of course you can. I'd consider just writing the copy operation as in 1.55 though (for the simple reason that it's not compiletime functionality anyways)

Comment: ok i just edited the copy.hpp directly into boost. I'll upgrade in a month or so anyways